# Is it OK to write self-tests for a module that depends on user input?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, user-input

Is it OK to write self-tests for a module that depends on user-input, or is this normally not done because the chance of the user making mistakes on input is too great?

Edit:

Suppose I have a function which returns `Hello World` when the user hits the `up_key` — then before testing the consequences of a wrong key-hit I would like to test whether the function returns really `Hello World` if the `up_key` was pressed.

Comment: By self-test, are you referring to unit testing the module?

Comment: I'm not confident with the technical terms: I copied `selt-test` from http://perldoc.perl.org/perlnewmod.html#Step-by-step:-Making-the-module

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is normal to write tests for a unit which requires input in part *because* "the user makes mistakes".  You have to determine the difference between valid and invalid input.  The unit/module should be tested not just to see that it does the right thing with valid input, but also that it does the right thing with invalid input (eg, recognizes it as such and returns an appropriate error).

Ie, part of the test should be intentionally feeding in invalid input.

Comment: Testing what should happen is generally brief, in comparison to testing that nothing bad happens with invalid/unexpected input!

Comment: If you want to test something, you have to test that it handles errors properly.  If it doesn't, that's a bug and very possibly a security vulnerability as well.  This is especially important where user input is concerned -- for an example, google "perl taint", which is commonly applied to CGI scripts for this reason.

Answer (score 3):

I usually think of user input as of a black box, attached to the main application. When testing, this black box is actually quite easy to replace with some mock object; then properties of this object are to be used as test parameters.

And, by the way, aren't you going to process the mistaken input somehow as well? )